# Why do I see a duplicate card listed in my Contacts on Mac and how do I prevent this?

Tags: macos

When viewing a contact (any contact) I see two cards listed (see image, personal details redacted). Why are there two there? This doesn't seem right? Maybe because I have family sharing? How do I get rid of the duplicate? Should I be worried about it?[image]

Comment: Do you have iCloud Contact syncing enabled?  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3384910?start=0&tstart=0 What's happening is that outlook has contacts and macOS has its own so basically Outlook is detecting both contacts

Comment: I do have iCloud contact syncing and I used to have outlook but no longer use Outlook on any of my Apple devices

Comment: Alright; So The problem is the reverse;  You will have to install Outlook, delete your contacts, then uninstall Outlook

Comment: I'm no longer at the company with the Exchange Server, so I cannot connect to it

Comment: Go to your iCloud settings and see if you're logged into 2 iCloud acct's.  Yes, you can do that.  My wife logs into my iCloud acct, so she can get the Contacts in my acct.  If you do NOT have 2 acct's, try renaming the 1 that's there, then go back to Contacts.  Did one of the card names shown in your pic change, or did they both change?  If both, then Contacts is somehow talking to the same iCloud acct twice.  I'd sign out of iCloud, check that your Contacts are empty, and sign back in.

Comment: @jimtut They both changed. So I signed back in to iCloud and both cards listed disappeared (for all restored contacts). So I guess that looks like it has fixed it? Thanks

Comment: Did you lose any contacts, or you just lost the duplicates?

Comment: I didn't lose any contacts, now there's just no "cards" section in the detail pane for any of the contacts, which is fine with me

Answer (score 0):

Provided as an answer to be able to post the picture...

Check System Prefs > Users & Groups.
Unlock the panel with the lock icon, bottom left.
Right click your name & choose Advanced Options...

You will be presented with a data sheet containing important aspects of your account - don't touch anything just yet.

Check at the bottom that you only have one of each contact method listed. Ignore the complex 'serial number' type aliases.

If you have two *identical* entries in aliases, you can remove one by selecting it & hitting the — key underneath.

Don't touch anything else!

Hit OK.
Reboot.

If there are no duplicates, hit Cancel, no reboot required.

[image]

Comment: I only have two different entries under aliases. One is my primary icloud email (it's not an @icloud.com email), the other begins com.apple.idms. So I just hit cancel ?? What now

Comment: See note above, jimtut helped me fix this by suggesting I sign out and back in to iCloud

Comment: Glad you got it [this wasn't a real answer, I just needed the formatting ;)